# Howto detect that maven plugin is executed inside maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to nicely recognize situation when maven plugin is executed from maven project or not, because I need different default parameters when execution is outside of maven project.

I can inject `@Component MavenProject project` into plugin Mojo, but this is setted to `test:test:jar:1` when there is no pom.xml.

I can inject base dir `@Parameter(defaultValue = "${basedir}") File baseDir` and check for `pom.xml` file, but this smells (with polyglot maven there is no pom.xml anymore).

How to check if project is executed inside or outside maven project?

---

I have specific goal and I want to use this same goal for both situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the question is not answered enough. My proposal is:

```
@Component
private MavenSession mavenSession;

boolean insideMavenProject = mavenSession.getRequest().isProjectPresent()
```

Comment: Thanks, why this code requires `maven-compat` as provided dependency?

Comment: @MariuszS, I'm not familiar with maven-compat. My plugin depends on maven-plugin-annotations 3.4 and maven-core 3.3.3

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that you clearly make a decision which goal should be used from CLI only and which should be used within the pom file... The basic decision can be made by using the following:

```java
@Mojo( name = "xxxx", requiresProject = true,... )
```

so the `requiresProject` means you need to have a `pom.xml` which means no calling via CLI.

If you omit this you can give the opportunity to use a goal from CLI. So best is to use one goal which is intended for calling from CLI and an other goal which is intended to be used from the pom.xml ..

Furthermore to inject a MavenProject you should do this like this:

```java
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project}", required=true, readonly=true)
private MavenProject project;
```

cause a MavenProject is not a `@Component`. Apart from that i don't understand your information about `test:test:jar:1` always...and what i'm interested in is what kind of plugin are you trying to write?

Comment: Plugin https://github.com/Codearte/accurest-maven-plugin/tree/master/maven-plugin, I want to run `generateStubs` without maven project. Injected MavenProject have MavenModel: `test:test:jar:1` when there is no pom.xml.